# Which data structure should be chosen? [Android Dictionary]

Tags: java, android, algorithm, dictionary

After several hours I've searched information from internet, I still feel not sure anything. My problem is: i want to implement a dictionary on android devices (java base), my requirements are speed and then memory-efficiency, but I couldn't make a decision on which data structure to use for searching.
I have a list of data structures, help me understands them and choose one:

- Ternary tree
- TRIE
- Aho–Corasick tree
- [...your suggest DS...]

And will be very kind if somebody can guide me about getting results (many fields: pronounce, mean, example sentence...) of word after we found it? We will save these info on another data file?

Comment: Your question is very confusing. That being said there is a built-in key-value pair data structure called HashMap: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: Also related to a http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Dictionary.html

Comment: Thanks for reading, my dictionary will be use an open-source dict data  file and then I will index them, may be several dictionary. I mean the words is very large and HASHMAP is not memory-efficient and can't give me list words that have same prefix. I plan to use one tree-DS. Please show me another guide

Comment: If you're concerned about memory (it might not really be a concern depending on the structure of the application--a server doing an auto-complete for instance with an EJB in memory) use an in-memory database or another sort of fail-over. You're only looking at like ~ 150K - 400K for most the common English language. Why don't you try it and see if you have a problem. A Trie is a joke to build and efficient for auto-complete. Especially if you use references.

Answer (score 1):

You need to list the major concerns of your design before searching data structures. What functions does this dictionary offer? What are the major features of it? Fast search? Space compactness? Insertion/deletion friendly? Cross-referencing friendly? Only when you have these in your mind you may measure how good a candidate structure is.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. As i said, i need it run fast, and then memory compactness. It will be able to search list words that have same prefix and common search as other dictionaries. I just be stuck in understanding about advantage and weak-point of these DS.

Comment: Trie and ternary tree are both good candidates for prefix search/list. Trie is faster but uses much much more space than ternary tree. Hashtable is fast too but doesn't support prefix list.

Comment: Thanksssss, and i don't know whether i miss a better DS or not, can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

It can be implemented in several ways, one of them is Trie. The route is represented by the digits and the nodes point to collection of words. Usage of trie is explained [here](http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=120)

Comment: Yeah, i see some good new from there. And can you show me where i can learn to create an open-source multi-dictionary as stardict-goldendict?

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Hunter Mcmillen's comment. In case you need the words to be sorted alphabetically like a regular dictionary you can use Java TreeMap which is a SortedMap.